# two ng-repeaters on the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with a list of items on it. Each row has a button. By pressing a button list item is added to another list on the same page (it's a typical "order" form). I'm using angular ng-repeater to show the first list. After user press a button an item info is added to JSON varaible. The question is what's the best way to show user's choice list on the same page? So far I'm think of adding an attribute to the first list so when user choose it, it'll be shown in the second list. But I also want first list to be modified by user without any changes to the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code and HTML; you'll get more informed and helpful answers.

Comment: Can't make any sense out of your question without some code context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code below, the button ng-click directive is calling the function AddtoList2($index) to add the current List1 item to List2, optionally it removes the current item from List1.

At template side

```
<div ng-repeat="item1 in List1">
     ...
    <input type="button" ng-click="AddtoList2($index)" />
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item2 in List2">
    ...
</div>
```

At controller side

```
   $scope.List1 = [];
   $scope.List2 = [];

   $scope.AddtoList2 = function (idx) {
       var item = $scope.List1[idx];
       $scope.List2.push(item);

        //If you want to remove from List 1
        $scope.List1.splice(idx, 1)
    };
```